# How to create multiple geometries in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

Hi I currently working with three.js, I would like to create 4 cubes in the 4 parts of the axis. I am able to create one cube that is rotating but how do I create the other three?, I have tried the clone () function and  position.set, but I cant seem to create another cube in a different axis. thanks for any help or guidance
Here is my javascript

```
var camera;
var scene;
var renderer;
var mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
    scene.add(light);

    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x050505, color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30 } );

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material );
    mesh.position.z = -50;
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    render();
}

function animate() {
    mesh.rotation.x += .04;
    mesh.rotation.y += .02;

    render();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    render();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the clone to the scene?

```
var newMesh = mesh.clone();
newMesh.position.x = 50;
scene.add(newMesh);
```

You can see a working codepen [here](http://codepen.io/guardabrazo/pen/rrwojZ).

Comment: ok thanks I will try it, and  ifI want to change one of the cubes for example it's texture can I still use clone?

Comment: I've updated [the codepen](http://codepen.io/guardabrazo/pen/rrwojZ) to show how to change the material of the cloned mesh. `newMesh.material = //Your new material`

Comment: Ok I got the 3 of the cubes the and I am able to change the material, what position should I do for the fourth position ( fourth quadrant)? I have position x , position y and position z,   should I now use position.set ( I tried it but it didnt work :-( ). Thanks much

Comment: What do you mean by fourth quadrant? If you want to put them in the shape of the XYZ axes you can try `mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0); mesh2.position.set(50, 0, 0); mesh3.position.set(0, 50, 0); mesh4.position.set(0, 0, 50);`.
Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your original question about cloning and make a new question if you need it.

Comment: Dead link as of today.